# VS Code is slow and freezing and then not responding

Tags: flutter, git, dart, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with VS Code: whenever I code, debug, or run the code on my physical device using Flutter, it gets very slow, freezes, and shows "Windows is not responding: Reopen!"
I disabled all the extensions, but nothing worked.
I even tried some commands like deleting the user directory and disabling the extensions, but I still faced the same issue .
I deleted the cache in AppData/Roaming/code, but still no luck.
I also deleted the code file, and the same issue still exists!
I even did this:
-Open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).
Run the Preferences: Configure Runtime Arguments command.
-Add "disable-hardware-acceleration": true.
-Restart VS Code.
I have looked it up all over the internet, and nothing worked!
Please help me!
these are the extntion:
[image]

Comment: Please let us know the specs of your windows machine and the physical device. Do you have any problems with the emulator?

Comment: Device Spec: Device name DESKTOP-P4APCKI
Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.60 GHz
Installed RAM 12.0 GB (11.9 GB usable)
Device ID 7B1CE693-8DEC-426E-B6FB-54CC3FADE82A
Product ID 00331-10000-00001-AA635
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch No pen or touch input is available for this display

Comment: my physical device is Galaxey A10s

Comment: and the emulator is not working

Comment: Can you run your app using the command line in a normal terminal?

Comment: Also, has VSCode ever worked for you?

Comment: Actually it run my my code in the avarge speed but what i'm talking about is after a period of time it  get slower and freezes then t shows the not respondig meeasge

Comment: Sounds like you are running out of memory or disk space but I haven't experienced this. Hopefully someone else can help.